# About knockoutjs - how to data-bind with text: and click:

Tags: events, binding, knockout.js, click, html

How are you guys? I'm new to the framework Knockoutjs, I wonder if I'm doing it right. (Need a little help.) :)

I have a tag  and would contain the same data-bind = text: anything and click: any function. The question is: Is it possible to do this? This is the correct way? Follow what I'm talking about: (I am using an example from the website itself) where when the user clicks the "Click Me" he adds +1 on the counter. I want that when the user clicks the tag  call the same function. :)

HTML:

```
<div>You've clicked <span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks, click: registerClick'>&nbsp;   </span> times</div>
```

JS:

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);

this.registerClick = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
};

this.resetClicks = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks(0);
};

this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.numberOfClicks() >= 3;
}, this);
```

};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());

Follows the file jsFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/3Lqsx/1718/)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have several binding pairs in one data-bind attribute.

You just have separated them with a comma ,

You asked :  I want that when the user clicks the tag call the same function.
But you already code it.

You can click on the counter or on the button it increments the counter.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for your time. I had already done this way ... and still is not what I need, I wonder if it has the anchor tag in <span> using comma (,) text: blabla, click: blabla. Several calls into a single object. Thank you again!

Comment: Do you want to execute several functions on the same element and on the same click ?

Comment: Come on ... Not exactly what I need :). is simpler! I want that when the user clicks the tag <span>, call the function (registerClick) without having to remove the "text:" property <span> tag. Thisway :
`<span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks', click:registerClick ></span>`

Comment: But it already works like you said. You are asking if you can do something you already did.

Comment: Oh sorry man! Actually already working! I was not clicking on the number! Apologies and Thanks!